# Unable to Push repository files to Remote Repository (GitHub)

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am new to Git & GitHub,

I have a local repository named HackerRank
I have a remote repository https://github.com/xxx/HackerRank.git

Now i wanted to push my local repository to remote repository.

I have used the following commands

```
git remote add hacker https://github.com/xxx/HackerRank.git
git push hacker master
```

It throwed the error

```
To https://github.com/xxx/HackerRank.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxx/HackerRank.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So now i tried to pull from my remote repository using the following command

```
git pull hacker master
From https://github.com/xxx/HackerRank
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> hacker/master
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Now i tried to fetch using the following command

```
$ git fetch hacker
From https://github.com/xxx/HackerRank
 * [new branch]      master     -> hacker/master
```

Now i tried to merge using the following command

```
$ git merge hacker/master
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: `refusing to merge unrelated histories` - you can't just push random stuff to an existing branch.

Comment: from your error log ,, you have to pull/fetch your rebo before pushing into it ! 'Integrate the remote changes (e.g.' git pull ...') before pushing again.'

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth       I have created a repository named HackerRank  in GitHub seperately ,as well as my local repository name is also HackerRank ,so i hope both should be same repository

Comment: @HassanAhmed ya i have tried to fetch and pull ,but even then it shows fatal:refusing to merge unrelated histories

Comment: @Renigunda - Yes, but by doing that, you have created two unrelated branch histories (exactly as the error message says).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth i agree with you ,Can you provide me a solution to fix it

Comment: sboye's answer below should basically work (assuming you haven't got grotesque conflicts).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth it worked out tanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to rebase your local branch on remote master branch and push it : `git pull --rebase hacker master`

You also can try to do a squash merge with `git merge --squash hacker/master`